# ENS domain name BID file lost help

Tags: ens

I backed up the BID, it saved as * .json file. But can not restore the four domain name. I just want to return to my ETHER. Please help。I have lost domain names "netcoin.eth", "hongkong.eth" "unionpay.eth" "porte -monnaie "
[image]

Comment: *"But can not restore the four domain name"* - What do you mean?

Comment: That is, importing a BID (*. Json) file can not restore the bid so that it can not reveal the seal price.

Comment: Are you importing the bid with the same account (ie: same account on MetaMask or Parity - whatever light-client you're using)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The client used is MIST. And logging in to the registrar.ens.domains page will take 20 minutes.

Comment: try another light client then, my favourite: https://myetherwallet.com and see if that helps